# Method of Moments Estimator for a non-standard distribution

Tags: statistics

How do you find the method moments operator for a non-standard distribution?

The pdf is $f(x) = ax^{-(1+a)}$, for $x\geq 1$ and the proposed solution is $\frac{\overline{x}}{\overline{x} - 1}$, where $\overline{x}$ is the mean of the sample.

I am familiar with the method of moments but cannot see how to arrive at that solution despite my best efforts. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: The mean of $X$ is given by
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = a\int_{1}^{\infty}xx^{-(1+a)}\text{ d}x  = a\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-a}\text{ d}x = a\left.\dfrac{x^{-a+1}}{-a+1} \right|_{x=1}^{x=\infty} = \left(0-\dfrac{a}{1-a}\right) = \dfrac{a}{a-1}\text{.}$$
Now for method of moments, what do you do with this value?

Comment: Shuffle it around to get an expression equal to â. Thank you :) !